SQLC generate: 'relation "users" does not exist'
I have a directory of migrations.
One of those migration files has the name of 20240718160024_initial_tables.sql
This migration file contains the sql to create the users table.
When I run sqlc generate i get the following error.
db/queries/users.sql:1:1: relation "users" does not exist

Now, if I create another file called "20240718160024_users.sql" to create the users table then it works.
Here is my sqlc.yml
version: "2"
sql:
  - name: "db"
    queries: "./db/queries"
    schema: "./db/migrations"
    engine: "postgresql"
    gen:
      go:
        package: "sqlc"
        out: "./internal/database/sqlc"
        sql_package: "pgx/v5"

And my users.sql query
-- name: GetUserByID :one
SELECT
    id,
    email,
    first_name,
    last_name,
    date_of_birth,
    phone_number,
    terms_accepted,
    created_at,
    updated_at
FROM users
WHERE id = $1
limit 1;

20240718160024_initial_tables.sql
-- +goose Up
-- +goose StatementBegin
create table if not exists users (
    id serial primary key,
    email varchar(255) unique not null,
    first_name varchar(100) not null,
    last_name varchar(100) not null,
    date_of_birth date not null,
    phone_number varchar(15) not null,
    terms_accepted boolean not null default false,
    created_at timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp,
    updated_at timestamp with time zone default current_timestamp
);
do $$
    begin
        if not exists (select 1 from pg_constraint where conname = 'email_format_chk')
        then alter table users add constraint email_format_chk check (email ~* '^[a-za-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-za-z0-9.-]+\.[a-za-z]{2,}$');
        end if;
    end
$$;
select set_updated_at_trigger('users');
-- +goose StatementEnd

-- +goose Down
-- +goose StatementBegin
drop table users;
-- +goose StatementEnd


This is difficult to answer without knowing what else is in your migration folder (do you have up and down files/how are your migration files laid out?). As the files are run in lexicographic order 20240718160024_users.sql will run after 20240718160024_initial_tables.sql, I'd suggest looking at statements that run between the two create table statements (sqlc basically just combines all of the files into a big string and removes roll back statements for a range of migration layouts).

Yes, there is an up and down that is correct in goose, it creates the tables in the db, the migrations files are ordered by their timestamped file name. I made an edit to include the goose file with it's name.

Can you please comment out that drop table and see if the problem persists? This should be ignored as sqlc will not process anything after the -- +goose Down but I think it's worth doing some testing to eliminate it as an option.
